# angular add element if last property is different in loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array with objects in my matches (as in games) controller:

```
    var tiles = [{name:"test",zPos:0},
     {name:"test2",zPos:0},
     {name:"test3",zPos:1},
     {name:"test4",zPos:2}]
```

In my html I loop the objects with:

```
    <p ng-repeat="tile in matches.tiles">
         z{{tile.zPos}} - {{tile.name}}
    </p>
```

How can I add an extra div like

```
<div class="newzindex"></div>
```

If the tile.zPos property is different from the last loop, so that I have one unique div per unique zPos property. The result I try to achive would look like

```
   <p>
         z0 -   test
   </p>
   <p>
         z0 -   test2
   </p>
   <div class="newzindex"></div>
   <p>
         z1 -   test3
   </p>
   <div class="newzindex"></div>
   <p>
         z2 -   test4
    </p>
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing for me: "different from the last loop" vs. "one unique div per unique zPos". Which one is it then? So if we stay at your example, if a `z0` comes after `z2`, should it create a new div then, or not?

Comment: @johnsmith in the loop (ng-repeat) i want to see if a property was the same as the previous iteration. If not i want to show a specific div

Comment: Roger, I would suggest to rephrase it in the question then. (But it might be just me... :))

Comment: @JohnSmith is on to something here with this comment;  Are you trying to group everything that is `z0` together, `z1` together, etc?  and if your data has `z0, z1, z2, z0`, are you wanting to display `z0` twice or grouped together? angular doesn't *evaluate* the values of each loop to make any decisions about future iterations....

Comment: @John Smith His question makes sense to me. Only add a new div if the `zpos` in the current iteration is different than the `zpos` from the last iteration.

Comment: @mariocatch exactly its hard to explain espacialy on mobile.

Comment: @mariocatch Yeah I got it now. I was just saying that "one unique div per unique zPos" would mean, that if there was another `{name:"test4",zPos:2}` at the end of the array then there shouldn't be a new div then. But - after clearing it up - there should be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` directives (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

**HTML**

```
<p ng-repeat-start="tile in matches.tiles ">
    z{{tile.zPos}} -   {{tile.tile.name}}
</p>
<div ng-if="matches.tiles[$index + 1].zPos != tile.zPos" ng-repeat-end class="newzindex"></div>
```